# A QuerySet from a recursive man-to-one model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

## Explanation

There is a `Tag` model. Tags are used in relation to other tags. For example, "New Year Gift", "Birthday Gift" are marked with the "Gift" tag:

Each tag can only be related with 1 other tag (the tree structure).

```
Lvl1:              Gifts
                   /    \
Lvl2: New Year Gifts    Birthday Gifts
                 /        \
Lvl3:         Card        Toys
```

### Database

Using Postgres database

### Model

Looks something like this:

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=64)
    tag = models.ForeignKey('self',
                            on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
                            blank=True,
                            null=True,
                            related_name='tags')
```

### Problem

Now all tags in the system are organised in 3 levels:

1. Top level
2. Sub-level
3. Sub-sub-level

E.g.: Gifts > Birthday Gift > Toy

### Goal

The goal is to construct a QuerySet which will return 3-level list, so it is passed into context and the template simply iterates over it and builds a 3-level DOM structure.

The ultimate goal is to solve this in the most efficient way (in terms of DB/CPU load).

I would think this could be done using annotating and some extra joins and values list. Any clues?

---

I was able to get something similar to what I need by using:

`Tag.objects.prefetch_related('tags').filter(tag=None).annotate(level1=ArrayAgg('tags__slug'), level2=ArrayAgg('tags__tags__slug')).values('name', 'level1', 'level2')`

Initial level0 has 3 items (top level tags). level1 returns correct list of slugs for each level0. Now just need to link level2 to the corresponding level1 items somehow.

Comment: This package might be useful [django-treebeard](https://django-treebeard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) also [django-mptt](https://django-mptt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Comment: I would like to stay away from 3rd party solutions unless it is unavoidable.